# Excel VBA Range Object

Tags: excel, range, vba

Why this throws me an error:

```
Dim Range_rng as Range

....

Range_rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(1).RefersToRange
```

According to MSDN documentation RefersToRange returns the Range object referred to by a Name object, so why I cannot assign it to Range_rng which is a Range object? (excel vba throws me a Object Variable or With block variable not set).

Comment: You need to use Set with object variables: `Set Range_rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(1).RefersToRange`

Answer (score 0):

A range is an object, so you have to use "Set":

```
Set Range_rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(1).RefersToRange
```